# Flutter OutlinedButton: set disabled color

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-widget

On my Flutter app i have an OutlinedButton with rounded corners:

```
OutlinedButton(
  child: Text(
    "a label",
  ),
  onPressed: () {
     // do something
  },
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: MyColor.colorAccent,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Now i need to style button for disabled status, but i don't need how to know with this widget (on EevatedButton i'm using  *MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith* as backgroundColor, but it's not good for OutlinedButton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the best practice but you can do something like this

```
bool? _isdisabled ;
//null check , if u are on an older version of dart of you want to declare it just do this :
bool _isdisabled = false;
 
OutlinedButton(
  child: Text(
    "a label",
  ),
  onPressed: () {
     // do something
  },
  style:_isdisabled==false? OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: MyColor.colorAccent,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  ): //another style ,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this code sample can help answer your question, sir.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isEnableButton = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              child: Text(
                "a label",
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (isEnableButton) {
                    isEnableButton = false;
                  } else {
                    isEnableButton = true;
                  }
                });
              },
              style:
                  isEnableButton ? enableButtonStyle() : disableButtonStyle(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  dynamic disableButtonStyle() {
    return OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.black,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  dynamic enableButtonStyle() {
    return OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.black,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```